# Facebook Connect Local Host

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

how would I go about checking if a user is logged in via facebook on my local host. I have the log in button and that works fine but I cannot determine if the user is logged in.

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0):

when a user is logged in using fb connect, there are some cookies values set,
so if you are using php sdk, you can do something like this to check

```
$Facebook = new Facebook(array("appId"=>FACEBOOK_API_KEY, "secret"=>FACEBOOK_SECRET));
if($FacebookUserID=$Facebook->getUser()) {
   // user is logged in in this case
}
```

replace appid and secret with ur own app's appid and secret

Comment: yes, but you have to create seperate app for localhost, I would suggest using a fake local domain name like myserver.local, and use hosts file and apache to resolve and and finally use that to register in fb application, localhost will work too

Comment: register a new app with domain name localhost, use those app ids when testing lcoally, it will work